# Hide and show contact form 7 field using Select optiond field values

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html-select, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 plugin for my carrier form. Right now i am hide/show some field using Select option values using java script.

Example:

IF First select box option value is (i) Faculty then display another Second select option field and if in First select box user select other options then hide second select options fields.

For this please see this screen shot -> http://nimb.ws/uxHNjy

For this i have used following JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#subject_forpost").hide();
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(".career_postapplied").change(function(){
       var value = this.value;
       if (value == "(i) Faculty"){
         jQuery("#subject_forpost").show();
       }
       else
       {
         jQuery("#subject_forpost").hide();
       }
     });
</script>
```

Above JS works good for me. But i have facing one issues in email body. When user select "(i) Faculty " options and then in second select option select any subject and again if user change their mind and in First select option select other options then second select options field hide. That's good but when admin received that mail then in email body also display Second select options values.

This one is issues. So How can i clear second select options value before form mail send if user change their mind and select other options in First select option field.

Thanks.

Comment: better you can try this one plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/

Comment: That plugin i have try but that not used for me.

Comment: Make sure you only have one .`career_postapplied` class in the HTML

Comment: Yes i have only one .career_postapplied class in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

I have added following code in **else** condition part and issues fixed.

```
jQuery("#subject_forpost").find('select').val('');
```

So working code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#subject_forpost").hide();
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(".career_postapplied").change(function(){
       var value = this.value;
       if (value == "(i) Faculty"){
         jQuery("#subject_forpost").show();
       }
       else
       {
         jQuery("#subject_forpost").find('select').val('');
         jQuery("#subject_forpost").hide();
       }
     });
</script>
```